# What CpupSyscallStub is?

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, profiling

I'm profiling my project with Visual Studio 2013, and the function doing most work is CpupSyscallStub - I was unable to find information about it in the internet, what is it exactly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CpupSyscallStub is, as the name suggests, a stub for making system calls. It's from wow64cpu.dll, which is part of the [WOW64](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384274%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) emulator that's used when running a 32-bit binary on a 64-bit kernel.

Comment: So, essentially there is no way to understand what is behind this call?